# Printing first 100 natural numbers and the first 2 multiples of 10 of each

Tags: matlab

I wanted to print first 100 natural nos. in matlab and their first 2 ten multipliers .So I did:

```
%to store first 100 natural nos. and their first 2 ten multipliers %

for i=1:100
y(i,1)=i;

end
j=1;
while(j!=3) do   

 for i=1:100   
  y(i,j)=y(i,j-1)*10;  

end  
end_while

%to write into txt file%

fileId =fopen('abc.m','w');

for i=1:100  
fprintf(fileId,'%7.2f\n',y(i,:));  
end  
fclose(fileId);
```

But it is not working and there is no error displayed...

Please help...

Comment: `j!=3` doesn't display an error? Or is that just a typo. Please explain what *...their first 2 ten multipliers...* means

Comment: Also where do you initialise `j`? And you don't change `j` in your `while` loop which means either (a) `j` is set to not be `3` (or just not set in which case it defaults to `sqrt(-1)`) earlier in the code in which case your `while` is a infinite loop or (b) `j` is set to `3` earlier in your code in which case your `while` loop never runs at all

Comment: @Dan their first 2 ten multipliers means that e.g. for 5 ,its first 2 multiples of 10 are 5*10,5*100.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so

```
for i=1:100
    y(i,1)=i;
end
```

is exactly the same as just

```
y = (1:100)';
```

no you want to multiply each of these numbers by `10` and `100` and concatenate these columns vectors into a matrix:

```
Y = [y, y.*10, y.*100];
```

Lastly write this all to a file:

```
fileId =fopen('abc.txt','w');
for row = 1:size(Y,1)
    fprintf(fileId,'%7.2f\t%7.2f\t%7.2f\n',Y(row, :));  
end
fclose(fileId);
```

or if you wanted a `.mat` file then just

```
save y
```

Comment: Is something displayed in the file?